# unable to generate second table in PPT report using openxml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I have this code. I am able to generate pptx report with text data perfectly. I have 4 tables as well in this report which has dynamic data. I am able to generate one table in PPT but unable to to do multiple.

**Requirement: On the right I have 4 tables.**
 [image]

**Expectation: I am able to get the 1st table.**
 [image]

In below code I have added 
`P.GraphicFrame graphicFrame2` in `AddNewSlide` method  in assumption of it will create another frame for table which I can fill with data and place on PPT. But it doesnt work. Please help.

```
using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(slideName, true))
            {
                //Get the first slide from presentation
                SlidePart intitalSlide = presentationDocument.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First();
                AddNewSlide(presentationDocument, intitalSlide, projectID, reportType);
            }

 #region Powerpoint Reports


    private System.Data.DataTable GetValueForPPTReport(int projectID)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select convert(varchar(10),proj_id) + ' : ' + proj_name as projName,proj_type, proj_problem_state, proj_goal_obj, proj_in_scope, proj_out_scope , proj_who_customer, proj_what_defect,proj_critical_to_qlty from tbl_proj_details where proj_id = @proj_id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@proj_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = projectID;
        dt = (new Bussiness()).Execute(cmd);
        return dt;
    }
    private System.Data.DataTable GetValueForPPTReportBenefit(int projectID)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select [proj_ben_type] as [Benefit Type], [proj_ben_year] as Year ,[proj_ben_fcst] as Forecast,[proj_ben_act] as Actual  from [tbl_proj_benefits_detail]  where proj_id = @proj_id";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@proj_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = projectID;
        dt = (new Bussiness()).Execute(cmd);
        return dt;
    }
    private void AddNewSlide(PresentationDocument presentationDocument, SlidePart _slideTemplate, int projectID, string reportType)
    {
        PresentationPart parent = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;
        var newSlidePart = parent.AddNewPart<SlidePart>("newSlide1");

        if (reportType == "Charter")
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = GetValueForPPTReport(projectID);

            //copy the contents of the template slide to the new slide and attach the appropriate layout
            newSlidePart.FeedData(_slideTemplate.GetStream(FileMode.Open));
            newSlidePart.AddPart(_slideTemplate.SlideLayoutPart, _slideTemplate.GetIdOfPart(_slideTemplate.SlideLayoutPart));

            //Alter the placeholder text in new slide
            SetPlaceholder(newSlidePart, "txtProjectIDName", dt.Rows[0]["projName"].ToString());
            SetPlaceholder(newSlidePart, "txtProjType", dt.Rows[0]["proj_type"].ToString());
            SetPlaceholder(newSlidePart, "txtProbSt", dt.Rows[0]["proj_problem_state"].ToString());
            SetPlaceholder(newSlidePart, "txtGoal", dt.Rows[0]["proj_goal_obj"].ToString());
            SetPlaceholder(newSlidePart, "txtDate", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
        }


        //Add dynamic Tables here

        ////List<OpenXmlElement> elements = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
        ////elements.Add(new P.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties
        ////    (new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 1, Name = "xyz" }, new P.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(), new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()));

        // Declare and instantiate the graphic Frame of the new slide 
        P.GraphicFrame graphicFrame = newSlidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new P.GraphicFrame());
        P.GraphicFrame graphicFrame2 = newSlidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new P.GraphicFrame());

        // Specify the required Frame properties of the graphicFrame 
        ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension() { Uri = "{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}" };
        P14.ModificationId modificationId1 = new P14.ModificationId() { Val = 3229994563U };
        modificationId1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("p14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main");
        applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension.Append(modificationId1);

        ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension2 = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension() { Uri = "{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}" };
        P14.ModificationId modificationId2 = new P14.ModificationId() { Val = 3229994564U };
        modificationId2.AddNamespaceDeclaration("p14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main");
        applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension.Append(modificationId2);

        graphicFrame.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties = new P.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties
        (new D.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 1, Name = "table1" },
        new D.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(new D.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
        new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtensionList(applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension)));

        graphicFrame2.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties = new P.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties
        (new D.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 2, Name = "table2" },
        new D.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(new D.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
        new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtensionList(applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension2)));

        if (true)
        {
            graphicFrame.Transform = new Transform(new D.Offset() { X = 5050609L, Y = 883400L }, new D.Extents() { Cx = 0, Cy = 0 });
            // Specify the Griaphic of the graphic Frame 
            graphicFrame.Graphic = new D.Graphic(new D.GraphicData(GenerateTable(projectID, reportType)) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table" });

            graphicFrame2.Transform = new Transform(new D.Offset() { X = 5050609L, Y = 983400L }, new D.Extents() { Cx = 0, Cy = 0 });
            // Specify the Griaphic of the graphic Frame 
            graphicFrame2.Graphic = new D.Graphic(new D.GraphicData(GenerateTable(projectID, reportType)) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table" });
        }
        //save the changes to the slide
        newSlidePart.Slide.Save();

        //need to assign an id to the new slide and add it to the slideIdList
        //first figure out the largest existing id
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.SlideIdList slideIdList = parent.Presentation.SlideIdList;
        uint maxSlideId = 1;

        foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.SlideId slideId in slideIdList.ChildElements)
        {
            if (slideId.Id > maxSlideId) maxSlideId = slideId.Id;
        }

        //assign an id and add the new slide at the end of the list
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.SlideId newSlideId = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.SlideId { Id = ++maxSlideId, RelationshipId = parent.GetIdOfPart(newSlidePart) };
        slideIdList.Append(newSlideId);

        //Delete first template slide 
        SlideId tempSlideId = slideIdList.ChildElements[0] as SlideId;
        slideIdList.RemoveChild(tempSlideId);
    }
    private void SetPlaceholder(SlidePart slidePart, string placeholder, string value)
    {
        List<D.Text> textListExif1 = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<D.Text>().Where(t => t.Text.Equals(placeholder)).ToList();
        foreach (D.Text text in textListExif1)
        {
            text.Text = value;
        }
    }

    #region tables

    /// <summary> 
    /// Generate Table as below order: 
    /// a:tbl(Table) ->a:tr(TableRow)->a:tc(TableCell) 
    /// We can return TableCell object with CreateTextCell method 
    /// and Append the TableCell object to TableRow  
    /// </summary> 
    /// <returns>Table Object</returns> 
    private D.Table GenerateTable(int projectID, string reportType)
    {
        // Declare and instantiate table  
        D.Table table = new D.Table();

        // Specify the required table properties for the table 
        D.TableProperties tableProperties = new D.TableProperties() { FirstRow = true, BandRow = false };
        D.TableStyleId tableStyleId = new D.TableStyleId();
        tableStyleId.Text = "{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}";

        tableProperties.Append(tableStyleId);
        D.TableGrid tableGrid1 = new D.TableGrid();
        System.Data.DataTable dtData = new System.Data.DataTable();
        if (reportType == "Charter")
        {
            //tblXBenefit
            dtData = GetValueForPPTReportBenefit(projectID);

            // Declare and instantiate tablegrid and colums 
            //D.TableGrid tableGrid1 = new D.TableGrid();
            D.GridColumn gridColumn1 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 1848000L };
            D.GridColumn gridColumn2 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 648000L };
            D.GridColumn gridColumn3 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 648000L };
            D.GridColumn gridColumn4 = new D.GridColumn() { Width = 648000L };

            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn1);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn2);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn3);
            tableGrid1.Append(gridColumn4);
        }
        table.Append(tableProperties);
        table.Append(tableGrid1);

        // Instantiate the table header row 
        D.TableRow tableHRow = new D.TableRow() { Height = 0L };
        for (int column = 0; column < dtData.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            tableHRow.Append(CreateTextCell(dtData.Columns[column].ToString()));
        }
        table.Append(tableHRow);

        // Instantiate the table data row 
        for (int row = 0; row < dtData.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            // Instantiate the table row 
            D.TableRow tableRow = new D.TableRow() { Height = 0L };
            for (int column = 0; column < dtData.Columns.Count; column++)
            {
                tableRow.Append(CreateTextCell(dtData.Rows[row][column].ToString()));
            }
            table.Append(tableRow);
        }
        return table;
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Create table cell with the below order: 
    /// a:tc(TableCell)->a:txbody(TextBody)->a:p(Paragraph)->a:r(Run)->a:t(Text) 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="text">Inserted Text in Cell</param> 
    /// <returns>Return TableCell object</returns> 
    private D.TableCell CreateTextCell(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            text = string.Empty;
        }

        // Declare and instantiate the table cell  
        // Create table cell with the below order: 
        // a:tc(TableCell)->a:txbody(TextBody)->a:p(Paragraph)->a:r(Run)->a:t(Text) 
        D.TableCell tableCell = new D.TableCell();

        //  Declare and instantiate the text body 
        D.TextBody textBody = new D.TextBody();
        D.BodyProperties bodyProperties = new D.BodyProperties();
        D.ListStyle listStyle = new D.ListStyle();

        D.Paragraph paragraph = new D.Paragraph();
        D.Run run = new D.Run();
        D.RunProperties runProperties = new D.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, FontSize = 800 };
        D.Text text2 = new D.Text();
        text2.Text = text;

        run.Append(runProperties);
        run.Append(text2);
        D.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties = new D.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false, FontSize = 700 };

        paragraph.Append(run);
        paragraph.Append(endParagraphRunProperties);
        textBody.Append(bodyProperties);
        textBody.Append(listStyle);
        textBody.Append(paragraph);

        D.TableCellProperties tableCellProperties = new D.TableCellProperties();
        tableCell.Append(textBody);
        tableCell.Append(tableCellProperties);

        return tableCell;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
```

Comment: Why  downvote and trying to close ?

Comment: you described that you have a problem, but you haven't explained what you have done to attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: In the code above I have tried adding ( P.GraphicFrame graphicFrame2, ApplicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension applicationNonVisualDrawingPropertiesExtension2 ) in AddNewSlide method in assumption of it will create another frame for table which I can fill with data and place on PPT. But it doesn't work, this all I tried and tried finding a lot about these frame classes but did not find out a single help on internet yet that how I can use it to generate more than one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so I could not find a way to generate multiple tables. What i did was place the placeholder in tempaltes table replaced the placeholder with values in

```
SlidePart.Slide.InnerXml
```